# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Hung / Frozen, Including Clock?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-jessie, troubleshooting, board-leds

I just happened to check on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B  with Raspbian Jessie 4.9.35-v7+ this morning and found it unresponsive.  IIRC, there is an LED that is normally on when the Pi is on, so I thought maybe the power supply had fried. 
 When I unplugged and replugged the power supply, the light I am referring to did NOT come on, but the activity light started flashing, and I was subsequently able to ssh into the device.  When I checked syslog, I saw the following:

```
Jun 22 17:17:01 dcu002pi CRON[4102]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 22 18:17:01 dcu002pi CRON[4124]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.4.2" x-pid="491" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Mounted Configuration File System.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Started Apply Kernel Variables.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Started udev Kernel Device Manager.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Starting Copy rules generated while the root was ro...
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Set preliminary keymap...
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi fake-hwclock[109]: Sat Jun 22 22:17:02 UTC 2019
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd-fsck[120]: e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd-fsck[120]: /dev/mmcblk0p2: clean, 36991/957712 files, 362194/3894528 blocks
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Started Copy rules generated while the root was ro.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mmcblk0p1.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1...
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd-fsck[229]: fsck.fat 3.0.27 (2014-11-12)
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd-fsck[229]: 0x25: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd-fsck[229]: Automatically removing dirty bit.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd-fsck[229]: Performing changes.
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd-fsck[229]: /dev/mmcblk0p1: 142 files, 2780/8057 clusters
Jun 22 18:17:14 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Started File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p1.
```

< snip >

```
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 192.168.11.52 UDP 123
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 fe80::ba27:ebff:fee7:de50 UDP 123
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: peers refreshed
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi ntpd[548]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi avahi-daemon[492]: Server startup complete. Host name is dcu002pi.local. Local service cookie is 2876740072.
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi kernel: [   17.782160] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:3 across:200700k SSFS
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi dphys-swapfile[513]: done.
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Started LSB: Autogenerate and use a swap file.
Jun 22 18:17:15 dcu002pi kernel: [   18.071759] random: crng init done
```

< snip >

```
Jun 22 18:17:19 dcu002pi systemd-hostnamed[579]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
Jun 22 18:17:19 dcu002pi dbus[496]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun 22 18:17:19 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 24 08:18:35 dcu002pi systemd[1]: Time has been changed
```

As far as I can tell, the RPi must have locked up so hard that the clock stopped running between 18:17:01 and 18:17:14 on 2019-06-22.  Prior to this, the device had been working fine, but I'm not sure what other logs to review.  The device runs a couple python scripts that are NOT resource intensive, and they are supposed to write logs IF anything goes wrong with them.  No logs were written by them.  Everything else in the OS is pretty much "stock."  In addition to not being sure what other logs it might make any sense to review, I'm not sure what to think of the fact the the power LED (if I am remembering correctly that there is one) seems to have gone out.  How should I troubleshoot this further?

Comment: I suggest to upgrade to Raspbian Stretch.

Comment: You said the following: "unplugged and replugged PSU, red light did NOT come on,  act light started flashing, and I was subsequently able to ssh into the device."  Almost always red LED on  means 5V OK.  And only 5V OK, then green LED flashes and boot up.  So it is 90% likely that 5V PSU is good, only the RED LED or related circuit faulty.  No indicator LED is no big problem.

Comment: I wasn't too concerned about the LED being off since things are working, but mentioned it in case it meant something.  I was much more concerned with the freezing up completely under little to no load.  The LED used to work, though, and I have a few GPIO pins bad, so maybe this is juts a defective Pi and I need to swap it out the next time something like this happens?